# $C^\infty$ extension operator

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $B_r$ denotes the ball $B(0,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $h \in ]0,1]$.

I am looking for the following extension operator :

$$P:C^\infty(B_h) \rightarrow C^\infty(B_2)$$

such that for all $u \in C^\infty(B_h)$, $P(u) \in C^\infty(B_2)$ verifies the following properties, for a fixed $s>3$

- $P(u)=u$ in $B_h$
- $||\nabla P(u)||_{(L^s(B_2))^3} \leq C_1 ||\nabla u||_{L^s(B_h)}$, with $C_1$ a positive constant independant of $h$ and $u$

My guess is that it might comes from a Sobolev operator extension. Any help or thoughts are welcomed !

Comment: I'm pretty sure Stein's extension operator does what you want it to. The reference is his book "Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions",

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work for just $C^\infty$-functions. Take $u(x):=\frac1{h^2-\|x\|^2}$.
It is infinitely often differentiable and unbounded on $B_h$. So it cannot be extended to $B_2$.

Comment: Humm I understand your points but I guess it depends on the definition used for $C^\infty$ functions. In my case, I want functions defined everywhere on $B_h$ and not almost everywhere (even though i'm looking at their norm in $L^p$ spaces). The Stein's book Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions" seems to have the answer i need in its dedicated section about extension.